# Is Traefik clustering not ready for production use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, traefik

Official traefik documentation says that clustering/high availability is still in beta, but how do I use it in production without high availability? If it isn't ready for production use, when does it get ready? I should consider switching to another reverse proxy if it doesn't get ready anytime soon.

https://docs.traefik.io/#features
https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/cluster/

Also, doc only states about sharing *backend/frontend configuration* between traefik instances. It does not clearly state what can be shared or cannot.

- Does it share number of http status codes across multiple traefik instances? If it doesn't, health status in dashboard and circuit breaker won't work correctly.
- How does it work with providers like ECS? In other words, does traefik save backend/frontend configurations obtained from Docker container labels? If it doesn't, each traefik instance might temporarily be in inconsistent state when new ECS task is launched, or existing one is stopped.
- Does it share health status of backend? It might try to stop the same ECS task twice when a task dies, if health status of tasks is not correctly shared.

Another problem I've found with clustering is that DynamoDB backend still doesn't support saving TLS certificates. I don't use this for now, though this might be another reason why it's still marked as a beta feature.

https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/4213

The doc doesn't seem to state that it's currently unsupported either.

https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/dynamodb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clustering features were indeed experimental in Traefik and were too much work for the team to keep up, which is why there's now [Traefik Enterprise Edition](https://containo.us/traefikee/), which should fit your exact needs. It's currently in Early access since December, but will soon come out. In the meantime, you can try it for free by getting a key [here](https://containo.us/traefikee/#traefikeeTryItModal).

It has several features that might be of interest to you:

- High availability
- Cluster dashboard
- Encrypted communication between nodes
- Separation of control and data plane (your docker socket is no longer accessible via the container that is exposed to the internet)
- The `traefikeectl` CLI that lets you operate your clusters very easily

To answer your questions, there are cluster-wide metrics, accessible through the dashboard, it works with all of the providers just like the open source version (since its core is still a standard Traefik server).